# How get FEDEX_ONE_RATE API using php

Tags: php, api, fedex

**How get FEDEX_ONE_RATE API using php**

I tried to get by **JeremyDunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper**
but not use standard rates comes good, when I tried to 'FEDEX_ONE_RATE' nothing change.

**Try 1**

```
$rateRequest->ShipmentSpecialServicesRequested->SpecialServiceTypes = 'FEDEX_ONE_RATE';
```

**Try 2**

```
$rateRequest->VariableOptions = array(SimpleType\ServiceOptionType::_FEDEX_ONE_RATE);
```

The above both method it's request are appended the parameter but results are nothing changed.

Any one help me.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without looking at your exact request, but assuming that your are submitting a `RateRequest`, then you need to:

1. Specify `FEDEX_ONE_RATE` as a `ServiceOptionType` in the `RateRequest.VariableOptions`.
2. Specify one of the supported Packaging Types (`FEDEX_SMALL_BOX`, `FEDEX_MEDIUM_BOX`, `FEDEX_LARGE_BOX`, `FEDEX_EXTRA_LARGE_BOX`, `FEDEX_PAK`, `FEDEX_TUBE`, `FEDEX_ENVELOPE`).
3. Specify a U.S. origin and a U.S. destination.

See the [FedEx documentation](https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/webhelp/ws/2020/US/FedEx_WebServices_2020_Developer_Guide.htm#t=wsdvg%2FHow_to_Specify_One_Rate_Pricing.htm) for all the details.

For example, using the following request:

```
<RateRequest>
  <WebAuthenticationDetail>
    <UserCredential>
      <Key>...</Key>
      <Password>...</Password>
    </UserCredential>
  </WebAuthenticationDetail>
  <ClientDetail>
    <AccountNumber>...</AccountNumber>
    <MeterNumber>...</MeterNumber>
  </ClientDetail>
  <Version>
    <ServiceId>crs</ServiceId>
    <Major>28</Major>
    <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
  </Version>
  <VariableOptions>FEDEX_ONE_RATE</VariableOptions>
  <RequestedShipment>
    <DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropoffType>
    <PackagingType>FEDEX_SMALL_BOX</PackagingType>
    <Shipper>
      <Address>
        <StateOrProvinceCode>TN</StateOrProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>38017</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
        <Residential>false</Residential>
      </Address>
    </Shipper>
    <Recipient>
      <Address>
        <StateOrProvinceCode>CA</StateOrProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>90028</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
        <Residential>false</Residential>
      </Address>
    </Recipient>
    <ShippingChargesPayment>
      <PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>
      <Payor>
        <ResponsibleParty>
          <AccountNumber>...</AccountNumber>
        </ResponsibleParty>
      </Payor>
    </ShippingChargesPayment>
    <RateRequestTypes>LIST</RateRequestTypes>
    <PackageCount>1</PackageCount>
    <RequestedPackageLineItems>
      <GroupPackageCount>1</GroupPackageCount>
      <Weight>
        <Units>LB</Units>
        <Value>10.00</Value>
      </Weight>
    </RequestedPackageLineItems>
  </RequestedShipment>
</RateRequest>
```

The corresponding response would be (I've omitted a lot of the details in order to highlight the important parts):

```
<RateReply>
  <HighestSeverity>SUCCESS</HighestSeverity>
  <Notifications>
    <Severity>SUCCESS</Severity>
    <Source>crs</Source><Code>0</Code>
    <Message>Request was successfully processed. </Message>
    <LocalizedMessage>Request was successfully processed. </LocalizedMessage>
  </Notifications>
  <Version>
    <ServiceId>crs</ServiceId>
    <Major>28</Major>
    <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
  </Version>
  <RateReplyDetails>
    <ServiceType>FIRST_OVERNIGHT</ServiceType>
      ...
    <PackagingType>FEDEX_SMALL_BOX</PackagingType>
    <DestinationAirportId>BUR</DestinationAirportId>
    <ActualRateType>PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE</ActualRateType>
    <RatedShipmentDetails>
      ...
    </RatedShipmentDetails>
  </RateReplyDetails>
  <RateReplyDetails>
    <ServiceType>FIRST_OVERNIGHT</ServiceType>
      ...
    <PackagingType>FEDEX_SMALL_BOX</PackagingType>
    <AppliedOptions>FEDEX_ONE_RATE</AppliedOptions>
    <DestinationAirportId>BUR</DestinationAirportId>
    <ActualRateType>PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE</ActualRateType>
    <RatedShipmentDetails>
      <ShipmentRateDetail>
        <SpecialRatingApplied>FEDEX_ONE_RATE</SpecialRatingApplied>
        ...
      </ShipmentRateDetail>
      ...
    </RatedShipmentDetails>
  </RateReplyDetails>
</RateReply>
```

I.e. for each `ServiceType` (e.g. `FIRST_OVERNIGHT`) two set of rates are returned: one without and one with the `FEDEX_ONE_RATE` applied (as highlighted by the presence of the `AppliedOptions` and `SpecialRatingApplied` elements in the `RateReplyDetails`).

Comment: @Deigo Colantoni

Here I tried requested are linked as google drive.
2 soap request and 1 array structure format.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_rbQP6Idjb6cDf6xTUMGJixjJhYYswSm?usp=sharing

You mentioned document  I read over more than 100 times.


If you have any format of rate request please send me, specially for FEDEX_ONE_RATE.

Comment: I've added a sample request (similar to your SOAP_Method_2.xml) and its corresponding response (where you can see the rates when FEDEX_ONE_RATE is applied). Compared to your request, the only things that I've changed are the key, password and account numbers, as well as the **rate service version** (**28** instead of 16). Also, it might be a good idea to omit the key, password and account numbers from your example files (or delete the files altogether). Hope it helps!

Comment: **Thanks for your effort.** I append your your code with my SOAP header. I tried only in the Postman but did not get result.<br/>

If omit the credentials code is working??<br/>

<br/>I tried with end point URL please confirm.  is that right? `https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services`

Comment: That url looks good. If you're using SOAP, try your SOAP_Method_2.xml: assuming that your test credentials and account numbers are correct, you just need to change the rate service version. I.e. amend your SOAP request and replace `http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v13` with `http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v28` and `<Major>16</Major>` with `<Major>28</Major>`. [Here](https://blog.postman.com/making-http-soap-requests-with-postman/) you can find details of how to make a SOAP request with Postman. And don't forget to report back the response you get, as that might shed some light on what is going on.

Comment: Thanks lot **Mr.Diego Colantoni**. I post my working and actual request, This sample request code surely, help some one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I got Resolved

This is the working code for postman (SOAP Request)**

`$url = 'https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate';` **//SAND BOX**

 `$url = 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate';` **// LIVE**

`$xml = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v28"> <SOAP-ENV:Body>`

`<RateRequest>`

`<WebAuthenticationDetail>`

`<UserCredential>`

`<Key>.....</Key>`

`<Password>....</Password>`

`</UserCredential>`

`</WebAuthenticationDetail>`

`<ClientDetail>`

`<AccountNumber>....</AccountNumber>`

`<MeterNumber>....</MeterNumber>`

`</ClientDetail>`

`<Version>`

`<ServiceId>crs</ServiceId>`

`<Major>28</Major>`

`<Intermediate>0</Intermediate>`

`<Minor>0</Minor>`

`</Version>`

`<VariableOptions>FEDEX_ONE_RATE</VariableOptions>`

`<RequestedShipment>`

`<DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropoffType>`

`<PackagingType>FEDEX_SMALL_BOX</PackagingType>`

`<Shipper>`

`<Address>`

`<StateOrProvinceCode>TN</StateOrProvinceCode>`

`<PostalCode>38017</PostalCode>`

`<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>`

`<Residential>false</Residential>`

`</Address>`

`</Shipper>`

`<Recipient>`

`<Address>`

`<StateOrProvinceCode>CA</StateOrProvinceCode>`

`<PostalCode>90028</PostalCode>`

`<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>`

`<Residential>false</Residential>`

`</Address>`

`</Recipient>`

`<ShippingChargesPayment>`

`<PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>`

`<Payor>`

`<ResponsibleParty>`

`<AccountNumber>.....</AccountNumber>`

`</ResponsibleParty>`

`</Payor>`

`</ShippingChargesPayment>`

`<RateRequestTypes>LIST</RateRequestTypes>`

`<PackageCount>1</PackageCount>`

`<RequestedPackageLineItems>`

`<GroupPackageCount>1</GroupPackageCount>`

`<Weight>`

`<Units>LB</Units>`

`<Value>10.00</Value>`

`</Weight>`

`</RequestedPackageLineItems>`

`</RequestedShipment>`

`</RateRequest>`

`</SOAP-ENV:Body>`

`</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';`